# Module-specific Controller plugins in Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

My Zend Framework project is divided into certain Modules.
Each Module has some specific Controller Plugins.

Now, the problem is that *all* plugins get loaded and registered (and thus, called) - no matter which module the user is trying to access.

I *could* test in which module we are and stop execution directly in the plugins, but I would have to do this in each and every plugin...

Is there an elegant way to register only module-specific plugins? Or am I trying to solve the wrong problem here?

Comment: How are you loading your module plugins at the moment? Via. application.ini or a bootstrap method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of Module specific Plugins

Taken from http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html

```
class Foomodule_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if ('foomodule' != $request->getModuleName()) {
            // If not in this module, return early
            return;
        }

        // Change layout
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('foomodule');
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
 in case you missed , there other ways listed in the same article above :

Isn't there a better way to do this?

Yes, likely there are better ways to accomplish this. The true problem is that modules are really second-class citizens in ZF currently. There are a few neat ideas floating around:
[Kathryn's Active module config](http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/zend-framework/177-active-module-based-config-with-zend-framework.html)

[Jeroen's Moduleconfig](http://www.amazium.com/blog/zend-framework-module-specific-config)

[Matthijs' ModuleConfig](http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/07/zend-framework-module-config/)

[Pádraic and Rob's Module Configurators proposal](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16023853)

Comment: Yep, but... Quite frankly, that is exactly what I _don't_ want - testing the Module Name in each and every Plugin.

Comment: @your Edit: I did miss this at first, but read it just some moments ago. Okay, seems like I have to wait for Zend Framework to live up to the expectations I had when I read about their module concept...